# How to implement gradient descent for a test function in R?

Tags: r

I have this code of gradient descent for a function with one variable x :

```
 # Having the number of iterations, step size, and start value be parameters the
# user can alter (with sane default values) I think is a better approach than
# hard coding them in the body of the function

grad<-function(iter = 30, alpha = 0.1, x_init = 1){

# define the objective function f(x) = sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x)
objFun = function(x) return(sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x))

# define the gradient of f(x) = sqrt(2+x)+sqrt(1+x)+sqrt(3+x)
# Note we don't split up the gradient here
gradient <- function(x) {
    result <- 1 / (2 * sqrt(2 + x))
    result <- result + 1 / (2 * sqrt(1 + x))
    result <- result + 1 / (2 * sqrt(3 + x))
    return(result)
}

x <- x_init

# create a vector to contain all xs for all steps
x.All = numeric(iter)

# gradient descent method to find the minimum
for(i in seq_len(iter)){
    # Guard against NaNs
    tmp <- x - alpha * gradient(x)
    if ( !is.nan(suppressWarnings(objFun(tmp))) ) {
        x <- tmp
    }
    x.All[i] = x
    print(x)
}

# print result and plot all xs for every iteration
print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x), " at position x = ", x, sep = ""))
plot(x.All, type = "l")  

}
```

I'm wanting to reproduce this for a function with two variables, for example, the Himmelblau's test function. I tried this but not working :

```
    grad<-function(iter = 40, alpha = 0.1 ){

  # define the objective function f(x) 
  objFun = function (x,y) return((x^2+y-11)^2+(x+y^2-7)^2)

  # define the gradient of f(x) 

  # Note we don't split up the gradient
   here



gradient <- function(x , y) {

  result <- c(4*x*(x^2+y-11)+2*(x+y^2-7),2*(x^2 + y - 11 )+4*y*(x+y^2-7))

        return(result)
      }
  init = c(6,6)

  x <- init[1]
  y <- init[2]
  # create a vector to contain all xs for all steps
  x.All = numeric(iter)
  y.All = numeric(iter)

  # gradient descent method to find the minimum
  for(i in seq_len(iter)){
    # Guard against NaNs
    tmp <- c(x,y) - alpha * gradient(x,y)
    if ( !is.nan(suppressWarnings(objFun(tmp))) ) {
      x <- tmp[1]
      y <- tmp[2]
    }
    x.All[i] = x
    y.All[i] = y
    print(x)
    print(y)
  }

  # print result and plot all xs for every iteration
  print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x,y), " at position x = ", x, sep = ""))
  plot(x.All, type = "l")  

  print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x ,y), " at position x = ", y, sep = ""))
  plot(y.All, type = "l")  

}
```

How can i solve the problem ? 
I should get a local minimum (3, 2 ) for this test-function :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization

Comment: I wish it's clear !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to increase the iteration number and try smaller step size.

I set `iter = 50000, alpha = 0.00001`

and obtain a solution that is very close to $(3,2)$.

```
[1] "The minimum of f(x) is 3.44890653837054e-11 at position x = 2.99999937324687"
[1] "The minimum of f(x) is 3.44890653837054e-11 at position x = 2.00000151311304"
```

[image]

Also, you might like to change

```
if ( !is.nan(suppressWarnings(objFun(tmp[1], tmp[2]))))
```

from

```
if ( !is.nan(suppressWarnings(objFun(tmp))))
```

Also, rather than print(x) and print(y) in separate line, you might like to do `print(c(i,x,y))`.

Comment: Yes but there is an issue with the second code i provided. It gives me an error " Y missing argument" . Also i should display the the vector (x,y) in the position not only x.

Comment: read my final comment about what to change.  The code does output both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: it gives this error :  Error in objFun(tmp) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

Comment: Could you copy & paste the full code you changed , Thank you a lot M.

Comment: change the line of code: 
if ( !is.nan(suppressWarnings(objFun(tmp[1], tmp[2]))) ){

Comment: Yes i understood, now it works well.                                                                                just last of all , how can i compute the used number of iterations. Where should  i add a counter in the for boucle ?

Comment: you can include    print(c(i, x,y)) at the last line of your for loop.

Comment: Great ! Thank you a lot for your valuable help M. Siong Thye Goh.    :)